# When I edited my html and js files, the console shows they are no longer connected

Tags: javascript, html, console

I am trying to do a webpage that runs functions that I built after you press a button and the first time I did it with four buttons I could get my functions to work and output on my webpage but after I added three more buttons for some reason it shows that my html and js are no longer connected and wont output to the website. I didn't take anything away from either webpage, just added the three new functions.
[image]

this image is what it looked like before I added my three new buttons and shows it working properly.

```js
function reverseStr(s) {
  var o = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i <= len; i++)
    o.push(s.charAt(len - i));
  return o.join('');
}


var ch = "b";
   
function isVowelR(ch,pattern){
 var pattern =/a|e|i|o|u|y/i ;
       if(pattern.test(ch)){
       return true;        
    }
      else{return false}
    } 
isVowelR(ch, pattern);



    function countVowles(str1)
{
  var vowel_list = 'aeiouyAEIOUY';
  var vcount = 0;
  
  for(var x = 0; x < str1.length ; x++)
  {
    if (vowel_list.indexOf(str1[x]) !== -1)
    {
      vcount += 1;
    }
  
  }
  return vcount;
}
console.log(countVowles(""));


function isDigit(regexp){
  var pattern = /[0-9]/;
    if(pattern.test(regexp)){
        return true;
    }
    else{return false}
}

function isPunct(param){
  var punc = /\W/;

  if(punc.test(param)){
        return true}
        else{return false}
}isPunct("");

function compress(s){
  return s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\s]/g,"");
}

var punctuationless = " ";

console.log(compress(punctuationless));

function isPalindrome(str){
    var str2 = reverseStr(compress(str));
        if(compress(str)) === str2}{
            return true;
        }
else{
    return false;
}
}



var main = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("inpt").value;
  var pattern =/a|e|i|o|u|y/i;
  var pattern2 = /[0-9]/;
    console.log(this.id);
   
    if (this.id == "btn1")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = reverseStr(str);
    else if (this.id == "btn2")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = isVowelR(str, pattern);
    else if (this.id == "btn3")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = countVowles(str);
      else if (this.id =="btn4")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = isDigit(str, pattern2);
      else if (this.id == "btn5")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = isPunct(punc,param);
      else if (this.id == "btn6")
          document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = compress(punctuationless,replace);
        else
           document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = isPalindrome(str,str2);
};  


window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

   
  
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", main);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' >
<title> Buttons Demo </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>String Machine</h2>
<p>
Enter a String: 
</p>
<input id= "inpt"> </input>
<button id="btn1">Reverse</button>
<button id="btn2">Vowel or no Vowel</button>
<button id="btn3">Count Vowels</button>
<button id="btn4">Digit or no Digit</button> 
<button id="btn5">Punctuation?</button>
<button id="btn6">Compress</button>
<button id="btn7">Palindrome?</button>
<br>
<hr style="width:23%; margin-left:0;">
<div id="outDiv"></div>
<script src="stringMach.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at this line:

```
if(compress(str)) === str2
```

Change it to

```
if(compress(str) === str2)
```